# SOLR - MYSQL - Query results

Tags: mysql, xml, solr

I'm working with SOLR and MySQL.

**This is my data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/meishidb" 
              user="root" 
              password="root"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id"
            query="SELECT 
                       p.id, 
                       p.occ_name
                   FROM 
                       BCARDS_OCCUPATION AS p">
            <field column="id" name='id'/>
            <field column="occ_name" name='occ_name'/>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**These are the rows added to schema.xml**

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="occ_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

The query works well, SOLR adds 'n' documents to the index. 
The problem is on querying the index; SOLR gives me results only if I type `'*:*'` and only about document ids (and not `occ_name`)!

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="q">*:*</str>
<str name="version">2.2</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="5" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">1</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">2</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">3</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">4</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">5</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

If I search for:

`id:1` gives me the doc with id=1

`occ_name:1` gives me 'undefined field occ_name'

why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you created `fieldType text` in your schema, but there's no such a fieldType in default schema.

Try using `type="text_en"` in your `occ_name` field definition.

And BTW (I always suggest the same thing), to examine what's really inside your index use the greatest Lucene tool ever, called [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/).

Comment: Thank you for the advice about Luke. Btw using 'text_en' didn't work AND on using Luke I can confirm that there is no 'occ_name' on the index

Comment: Take a look at your schema.xml and examine what kind of field types you have defined (fieldType). Then declare your occ_name field accordingly. So make this change, restart Solr and reindex.

Comment: The field types I have defined in schema.xml are indicated in my Question! I think I have defined them in a wrong way ... but I can't see the mistake (I changed 'text' with 'text_en' in occ_name field, as you suggest me).

Comment: You did not understand what I meant, the elements of type fieldType are defined in your schema. That's the place where you can see (and configure if needed) which field types are defined. Depending on the type of value that goes in your occ_name field you'll define its type. Maybe you don't even have fieldType text_en (only in newer versions). That's why I suggested you to check. Have you re-indexed your data after changing field type?